# jquery how to display a map using AJAX data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently working through a project with the following requirements

1. create a button called “city map” in the page.
2. Once a country is selected and the list of cities are loaded using AJAX get method, click the button to open a new
   window which displays the selected city map.
3. Whenever the city is changed in the
   selection list and the button is clicked, a new window with the selected city map will
   be displayed.

```
<html>
<head>
   
   <style>
        body {
            background-color: #E8EAF6;
        }
        main {
            margin: 1em;
            width: 60%;
            padding: 1em;
        }
        select {
            padding: 0.5em;
        }
        #results {
            margin-top: 0.5em;
        }
   </style>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(function() {
       $("#country").change(function() {
           var param = "iso=" + $('#country').val();
      $.get("http://www.randyconnolly.com/funwebdev/services/travel/cities.php", param)
          .done(function (data) {
              var select = $("<select id='cities'></select>");
              // alternate way to loop through an array using jquery $.each() method
              $.each(data, function(index,city) {
                  select.append('<option value="' + city.id + '">' + city.name + "</option>");
              });
              $("#results").empty().append(select);                
          })
          .fail(function (jqXHR) {
              alert("Error: " + jqXHR.status);
          })
          .always(function () {
              console.log("service cities request finished");
          });
       });
   });
   </script>      
</head>    
<body>
    <main>
      <select id="country">
          <option value=0>Select a country</option>
          <option value='CA'>Canada</option>
          <option value='FR'>France</option>
          <option value='DE'>Germany</option>
          <option value='IT'>Italy</option>
          <option value='US'>United States</option>
      </select>

      <div id="results"></div>

      <button> city map </button>
   </main>


</body>   
</html>
```

I have managed to do the above, which is accessing the city once a country is chosen. However I'm not sure how to implement the actual map feature.

I came up with the following pseduo, however I'm unsure of where to go from there

```
return array(
{id: cityId, name: cityName, etc.....},
)
```

Comment: So you just added the button, city map and thats it? What have yout tried, what maps are you gonna use?

Comment: we were given this link https://www.google.com/maps/place/49%C2%B003'28.7%22N+122%C2%B015'09.3%22W/@49.05798,-122.25257,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d49.05798!4d-122.25257 to work with

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand you want to open a new tab containing the map of that city. Right?
If so, the answer is quite simple.
If you take a look over an object for a certain city it contains the latitude and longitude for that city. For example: "latitude":"5.55602","longitude":"-0.1969".

1. **If you want to use google maps they have a documentation for coordinates**
   https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

You just have to interpolate the coordinates from the API inside the url and open the link in a new tab.
I wasn't able to run your example but here is a hint:

```
const city = {id:"",name:"Darmstadt",iso:"DE",latitude:"49.87056",longitude:"8.64944",population:"140385",elevation:"145"}
function openMap(city){
    const mapUrl = `https://www.google.com/maps/place/${city.latitude}+${city.longitude}`;
    window.open(mapUrl, '_blank').focus();
}
```

You can then bind this function to the button and pass the selected map.

2. **If you want to embed the map into your website, please follow this tutorial:**
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map#maps_add_map-javascript

Hope it helps. Let me know if you have questions about something.

Comment: Another solution would be to embed the mapUrl using the <iframe> tag. I wouldn't recommend doing that, since their embed documentation is easy to understand and the library is well maintained.

Comment: I think its more converting the php to a json and then using the json